# TreeView - how to use the role as an image source

Tags: qt, treeview, qml

I have a simple treeview model with defined roles. 
Here is a code:

```
TreeView {
        model: theModel
        itemDelegate: Rectangle {
            color: ( styleData.row % 2 == 0 ) ? "white" : "lightblue"
            height: 20
            Text {
                text: styleData.value === undefined ? "" : styleData.value
            }
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            width: 100
            role: "name_role"
            title: "Map"
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            width: 50
            role: "description_role"
            title: "Description"
        }

        Image {
            width: 15
            source: description_role + ".png"
            }

    }
```

In the second column i've got correct description displayed, but when i use this role as an image source i've got mistake "role is undefined".

The question is: How to correctly define role as an image source?

Comment: The `Image` object doesn't relate to `itemDelegate`, so where do you want it will be painted?

Comment: It will be painted in the TreeView, as the columns do. ItemDelegate only describes the view of the cells. Anyway, putting image inside the itemdelegate doesn't change anything - still role is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer, by reading documentation of the TableViewColumn
The QML treeView should be like this:

```
TreeView {
    model: theModel
    itemDelegate: Rectangle {
        color: ( styleData.row % 2 == 0 ) ? "white" : "lightblue"
        height: 20
        Text {
            text: styleData.value === undefined ? "" : styleData.value
        }
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 100
        role: "name_role"
        title: "Map"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 50
        role: "description_role"
        title: "Description"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 50
        role: "description_role"
        title: "Icon"
        delegate: Image {
            source: styleData.value + ".png"
            }
        }

}
```